# If i change anything in JSON file after deploying into production, changes not reflecting if i browse

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript

I am supporting multiple languages in my project, for that i maintained one JSON file, after deploying it into production if i change anything in that JSON file it is not reflecting after browsing.

If i change anything in production JSON file, it should reflect in live.

Comment: You'll need to tell us how your json file is stored, how your read it and how you change it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is related to `asp.net`, `react` & `typescript`. This reads more like a caching issue, which is done by your web server. At least, if the JSON file is requested by the clients browser (`GET /path/to/file.json`). What `max-age` have you set for `json files`? Is this file versioned (`file.01234567.json`)? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well if you do not make the chamads in real time there is no way to get the result by magic, if ouver changes in json this will only be verified if the react makes a new query in api, in the case of assembly of the component a new query is performed and then the new values update.